# Best practice for long string literals in Go

Tags: string, go, literals, idioms

I've got a long string literal in Go:

```
db.Exec("UPDATE mytable SET (I, Have, Lots, Of, Fields) = ('suchalongvalue', 'thisislongaswell', 'ohmansolong', 'wowsolong', 'loooooooooooooooooooooooooong')")
```

I see two ways to make this more manageable: raw quotes, or multiple concatenated quotes:

```
db.Exec(`UPDATE mytable SET (I, Have, Lots, Of, Fields) 
         = ('suchalongvalue', 'thisislongaswell', 'ohmansolong', 
            'wowsolong', 'loooooooooooooooooooooooooong')`)

db.Exec("UPDATE mytable SET (I, Have, Lots, Of, Fields) = " + 
    "('suchalongvalue', 'thisislongaswell', 'ohmansolong', " +
    "'wowsolong', 'loooooooooooooooooooooooooong')")
```

The first feels more right, but the preceding spaces will be included in the string, making the resulting string have awkward runs of spaces in it. Is either of these considered idiomatic Go?

Comment: Use raw quotes. Ignore indentation for strings with raw quotes.

Comment: What do you mean, "ignore indentation"? Is there a way to get the compiler to do this, or do you mean that I should use raw quotes and not indent stylistically?

Comment: Exactly. Do not indent stylistically when using raw quotes. That's how all the standard code does it.

Comment: @FuZxxl do you want to go ahead and make that an answer? Here's a link you can use as an example http://golang.org/src/cmd/go/main.go#L172 :)

Comment: @MatrixFrog, I think your link is not relevant anymore...

Answer (score 7):

This is what I do:

```
q := `UPDATE mytable SET (I, Have, Lots, Of, Fields) = ` +
     `('suchalongvalue', ` + 
     `'thisislongaswell', ` +
     `'wowsolong', ` + 
     `loooooooooooooooooooooooooong')`

db.Exec(q)
```

I think it looks a lot cleaner

Comment: This method is very ineffecient. Because `+` might reallocate memory and copy strings many many times.

Answer (score 5):

It looks weird putting the long string literal in the parameter like that. I would prefer:

```
const updateQuery=`
UPDATE mytable SET (I, Have, Lots, Of, Fields) 
= ('suchalongvalue', 'thisislongaswell', 'ohmansolong', 
'wowsolong', 'loooooooooooooooooooooooooong')`

func doUpdate(){
  db.Exec(updateQuery)
}
```

I also prefer a single newline at the beginning to the odd spaces in each line. That way you can kill it with `strings.Trim` if it causes problems.

Comment: That's a good idea, although I'd put the constant inside the function since it's not needed in the global scope.

Comment: If your string is a constant, you could use any form you like, the compiler will do the concatenation for you. Just go for whatever form is visually more appealing to you. In any other case, the backquote syntax is the way to go. You can even break the line right after`const updateQuery =` and put the first backquote on the following line for proper alignment if you're picky.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer:

```
var updateStatement = `
    UPDATE
        mytable
    SET
        I = 'suchalongvalue'
        ,Have = 'thisislongaswell'
        ,Lots = 'ohmansolong'
        ,Of = 'wowsolong'
        ,Fields = 'loooooooooooooooooooooooooong'
`
func update(updateStatement string) {
    db.Exec(updateStatement)
}
```

Should looks much more cleaner. At least thats been taught to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
s := `UPDATE mytable SET (I, Have, Lots, Of, Fields) = `
s += `('suchalongvalue', `
s += `'thisislongaswell', `
s += `'wowsolong', `
s += `loooooooooooooooooooooooooong')`

db.Exec(s)
```

Comment: I use this method for stringing html together whilst keeping it readable. This method allows a string to be separated across many lines without including new line characters.

Comment: This is rather inefficient, as strings are immutable.  Each `+=` is going to allocate a new string.  If you must do it this way (as opposed to raw quotes), consider using a `bytes.Buffer`.

Answer (score 1):

Since we're talking about SQL in this instance…

It is rare to pass string literals as column values in an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. You'll almost always be passing in computed values from code, in which case it's far better to use parameterized queries. In the rare case where you do know a value at compile time, parameterization is still generally the right answer:

```
_, err := db.Exec(
    `UPDATE mytable SET (I, Have, Lots, Of, Fields) = ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)`,
    "suchalongvalue",
    "thisislongaswell",
    "ohmansolong",
    "wowsolong",
    "loooooooooooooooooooooooooong")
```

Comment: This question is about long string literals.