# indentation style for multi-line string literals

Tags: go

What is the proposed style for indenting a raw string literal? If I indent it based on its first line, it might not align properly in editors that have a different tab length. For example:

```
if select == nil {
    select, err = db.Prepare(`select name
                              from table
                              where id=$1`)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
}
```

I have found this question, but I am still unclear: [Best practice for long string literals in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940194/best-practice-for-long-string-literals-in-go)

Should I do it like below?

```
if select == nil {
    select, err = db.Prepare(`
select name
from table
where id=$1`)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering both propositions would add newline or spaces to the litteral string, I would favor (even though [`fmt` format the first line](http://play.golang.org/p/5phsUhq9N2)):

```
    select, err = db.Prepare(
     `select name
from table
where id=$1`)
```

As the [OP akonsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410102/akonsu)  comments below,  it seems consistent with the style of the golang code itself, as seen in [`src/cmd/go/main.go#L175`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5282e3ab26dd01180640a1a0e59ed5a4d070ba44/src/cmd/go/main.go#L175-L198), which keeps the first line at the level of the opening '`(`'

```
var usageTemplate = `Go is a tool for managing Go source code.
Usage:
go command [arguments]
...
`
```

Comment: ok, but this one won't work because `go fmt` will indent the first line.

Comment: @akonsu that is what i just saw indeed. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks. this is consistent with the style of the golang code itself: http://golang.org/src/cmd/go/main.go#L174

Comment: The way that breaks the indentation of the surrounding code is pretty ugly... This might be the best solution, but it's not a good one.  Eg, compare with ruby's [squiggly heredoc solution](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2016/01/06/about-the-ruby-squiggly-heredoc-syntax/) to this same problem.

Comment: @Jonah I agree. I haven't seen any evolution proposed for Go 2 though... https://github.com/golang/go/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3AGo2+string+literal&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 7):

You may be interrested by [github.com/lithammer/dedent](https://github.com/lithammer/dedent) package which provide something similar to Python std textwrap.dedent().

```golang
if select == nil {
    select, err = db.Prepare(dedent.Dedent(`
        select name
        from table
        where id=$1
    `)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding SQL, the whitespace doesn't matter, so it's just a personal preference. In my case, as SQL is a different language from Go, I like to make sure that the SQL code shares no lines with Go code:

```
if select == nil {
   select, err = db.Prepare(`
   select name
   from table
   where id = $1
   `)
   if err != nil {
      return nil, err
   }
}
```